# Don't show backbutton if index > 0

Tags: flutter

I have a scaffold and on the **leading** of **AppBar** a custom back button.
I have a int `refIndex` that initially is 0, but changes to the same value as the `index` of `Pageview.builder` changes

I want the backbuttnn to disappear if the `refIndex > 0`. I have no idea why its not working.

```
Widget leadingWiget() {
if (refIndex == 0) {
  return IconButton(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.chevron_left,
      color: Colors.black,
      size: 40,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      // Navigator.of(context).pop();
      print(refIndex);
    },
  );
}
return const SizedBox(height: 0, width: 0);
}
```

EDIT: I have the var declared right after the class class `_QuestionsPageState extends State<QuestionsPage> {`

in `Pageview.builder`, after `itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {` I have `refIndex = index;`

Is it wrong? I'm facing the same problem if I want to display the refIndex. The value itself changes when I change pages, but the displayed is the same as the initial, 0.

Comment: Are you sure about refIndex value. Print it. There is no else condition. Put empty widget to else. Btw i advice to use container() instead of sizedbox.

Comment: @LacOniC I'm sure. If I just assign height and width to a container flutter advice to change to SizedBox

Comment: @LacOniC Added print right after refIndex = index and on the button. Values match

Comment: @LacOniC edited question

Comment: Probably you can not catch change. I guess it's about state management. For example i use GetX and i would put that widget in Obx to listen changes. Try to listen changes.

Comment: You print refIndex in first condition. So it will always show 0. Problem is in if it's not 0. It's coming always 0, problem is that. Right? So you should find why it's always 0.

Comment: it doesn't always show zero. When refIndex is 1 it prints 1. The thing is that the if condition is only taking the initial value of the variable (0), as if the state of the var didn't change

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visibilty Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html).

For example:

```
Visibilty(
  visible: refIndex == 0,
  child: IconButton(...),
)
```

Comment: Edited question